# Why can't I overwrite files in a directory given by "filedialog.askdirectory"?

Tags: python, tkinter

I would need a script that owerwrites every file with `.prj` extension in a gven directory, and writes a certain string in these files. I started with this code to check if it works, and it works perfectly if I copy and run the `.py` file from the desired directory:

```
import os

for file in os.listdir("./"):
    if file.endswith(".prj"):
        with open(file, "r+") as f:
            f.truncate(0)
            f.write('Some text')
```

Then I added a feature where I can select the desired directory, so I would not have to copy the `.py` file every time.

```
import os
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory

path = askdirectory(title='Choose a directory')
for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.endswith(".prj"):
        with open(file, "r+") as f:
            f.truncate(0)
            f.write('Some text')
```

Unfortunately this does not seem to work. I checked, and the `path` and `file` variables got the same values in both codes, so I do not know where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `open(file,'r+')` if you are not in the directory of the file.
You have to specify the path:

```
open(path+"/"+file, "r+")
```

Comment: Oh Jesus, this is embarassing... So obvious, yet I got over it so easily. Thank you!

Comment: It's not really embarassing. It happens to me on a regular basis. That's how I spotted the mistake ;)

Answer (score 1):

`os.listdir()` returns filenames only without the parent directory information.  Use `os.path.join(path, file)`:

```
path = askdirectory(title='Choose a directory')
for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.endswith(".prj"):
        with open(os.path.join(path, file), "r+") as f:
            f.truncate(0)
            f.write('Some text')
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how could I not find this error.